# Python binary search trows index out of range

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, search, binary

```
def binary_search(arr, key):
    store_middle = 0
    length = len(arr)
    while store_middle <= length:
        middle = (store_middle + length) // 2
        if arr[middle] == key:  # throws list index out of range
            print(f"Key: {key} is in the {middle} list index")
            break
        else:
            if arr[middle] < key:
                store_middle = middle + 1
            else:
                length = middle - 1
    return key


binary_search([2, 3, 5, 8, 14, 12], 14)
```

The function searches for the 'key' in the given array. When I provide the 'key' larger than 12 the function throws 'list index out of range'. I can't figure out the reason why, it doesn't make any sense why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

```py
while store_middle <= length
```

When `store_middle = length`, you'll cause the error, since the last valid index has value `len(arr)-1`. Just change it to

```
while store_middle < length
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things:

- When `store_middle` and `length` both equal to `len(arr)`, `mid` will be out of bounds according to the existing logic.

  To fix this, either set `length = len(arr) - 1` or update the loop
  condition to be `while store_middle < length`. The former is usually
  preferred as it can be easily updated to find a "lower bound".
- Binary search works on a sorted container. If you're trying to find something in this array `[2, 3, 5, 8, 14, 12]`, binary search won't work.